# Combine 2 XML to Json

Tags: json, algorithm

I am finding a solution for problem as below:

**Case 1:**

XML Template

```
<Root> 
    <ID>{{id}}</ID> 
    <NAME>{{info.name}}</NAME>
</Root>
```

XML Request

```
<Root> 
    <ID>1</ID>  
    <NAME>Alex</NAME>
</Root>
```

**Case 2:**
XML Template

```
<Root> 
    <PAIR>
        <NAME>ID</NAME> 
        <VALUE>{{id}}</VALUE>   
    </PAIR>
    <PAIR>
        <NAME>NAME</NAME>   
        <VALUE>{{info.name}}</VALUE>    
    </PAIR>
</Root>
```

XML Request

```
<Root> 
    <PAIR>
        <NAME>ID</NAME> 
        <VALUE>1</VALUE>    
    </PAIR>
    <PAIR>
        <NAME>NAME</NAME>   
        <VALUE>Alex</VALUE> 
    </PAIR>
</Root>
```

For all these 2 cases, I want to combine and generate a json based on template, for exemple:

```
{"id": 1, "info": {"name":"Alex"}}
```

Thanks a lot!

`{"id": 1, "info": {"name":"Alex"}}`

Comment: Did you try some XML to JSON tools? https://www.codingbeautydev.com/blog/javascript-convert-xml-to-json